# How to set logback file path with spring?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, logback

I have JavaEE application that uses Spring and Logback.

I want be able to set log file path in application.properties file (which stores Spring properties).

Setting property `${path.to.log.file}` in `logback.xml` do not work (and it's understandable). What is good way to do it then?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Spring [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging) documentation:

1. Make sure that you exclude `commons-logging` from Spring dependencies. Note that this exclusion may happen for more than one module of Spring.
2. Assuming that you're using SLF4J, make sure that you also include `jcl-over-slf4j` in your dependencies.
3. Include the proper Logback dependencies that you need.
4. Place `logback.xml` configuration in the root of your [classpath](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

Probably something like this finally:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${version.spring}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>${version.logback}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this will be by setting a property for logpath in system variable.

Suppose you are using tomcat, then in your setenv.bat/setenv.sh file set the property as

-Dpath.to.log.file="/home/birendra/"

Now you can refer the path in your logback.xml

Comment: The fact is that I am using tomcat, but my goal is to make deployment as simple as possible. That's way I want to move all necessary properties to one file.